# Difference in url include pattern with or without url

Tags: python, django

What's the difference, if any, between the two patterns below, regarding performance, best practices, etc? What's the preferred method?

```
url(r'^my-app/', include('my-app.urls'))
```

vs

```
(r'^my-app/', include('my-app.urls'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Django 1.8, best practice is for urlpatterns to be a list of `url()` instances.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/2003/$', views.special_case_2003),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', views.year_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/$', views.month_archive),
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]+)/$', views.article_detail),
]
```

In older versions of Django, urlpatterns was a [`patterns`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#patterns) instance, and you could use tuples instead of a `url()` instances. However `patterns` is deprecated, and will be removed in Django 1.10.

See the Django 1.8 [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#django-conf-urls-patterns) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

**Django in version 1.8** recommends that `urlpatterns` should be a plain list of [`django.conf.urls.url()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.url) instances.

> urlpatterns should be a plain list of `django.conf.urls.url()` instances.

It should be something like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^my-app/', include('my-app.urls')),
    ....
]
```